Uploading a video(file) through file explorer in Unity WebGl
I'm developing a game on Unity WebGl. I have a part that user has to upload a video through file explorer, then I have to send it to server. I don't have to play it in unity. I just need to get the file and send it to the server.
Is there any way to do that through Unity and not javascript plugins? If there is no way for that, could you introduce a plugin to do so?
I appreciate your help in advance:)

I would suggest to do this on a separate html page and not from within the Unity game. Then you can just use a normal html file upload form, you don’t need any plugin. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

yes, you can upload files..  what exact issues are you having

So if you really just want to trigger an upload you can do most - or actually all of it JavaScript sided. But yes, the only thing you need on Unity side is a simple plugin with a parameter-less method to kick the process off (see Call JavaScript functions from Unity C# scripts).
You can simply create an ad-hock hidden <input type="file"> via JavaScript code, add a callback for once a file is selected and then trigger click on it also via code.
Then you can further use e.g. fetch or where not supported as a fallback XMLHttpRequest to submit the file via POST request to your server API.
This could look like e.g.
VideoUpload.cs
public static class VideoUpload
{
    // jslib plugins are automatically built into this
    [DllImport("__Internal")]

    // Note: Name has to match with the function name in jslib file
    private static extern void TriggerVideoUpload();

    public static void TriggerUploadViaFileBrowser()
    {
#if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR
        TriggerVideoUpload();
#else
        throw new NotSupportedException("This method is only supported in WebGL builds");
#endif
    }
}

VideoUpload.jslib
const VideoUpload = 
{
    // NOTE: function name has to match exactly the c# method name
    TriggerVideoUpload: function() {
        //TODO! video file extensions your server can handle
        // e.g. 
        const extension = '.mp4,.avi,.mov,.wmv,.flv,.mkv';
        // or simply
        //const extension = 'video/*';

        //TODO! replace by your server API url
        const serverAPI = 'https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/files/upload';

        //TODO! replace by your required API method
        const httpMethod = 'POST';
        
        // create a hidden File input element
        const input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "file";
        input.accept = extension;
        input.setAttribute("hidden", true);
        input.onchange = function(e) {
            // remove this temporary input element again
            document.body.remove(input);
    
            // get selected file
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            if (file) {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', file);
            
                // Check if fetch is supported
                if (window.fetch) {
                    // Use fetch API
                    fetch(serverAPI, {
                        method: httpMethod,
                        body: formData
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log('Success:', data);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    });
                } else {
                    // Use XMLHttpRequest as fallback
                    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open(httpMethod, serverAPI, true);
                
                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            // Request succeeded
                            console.log('Success:', JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                        } else {
                            // Request failed
                            console.error('Error:', xhr.statusText);
                        }
                    };
                
                     xhr.onerror = function() {
                       // Request failed
                       console.error('Request failed');
                     };
                
                     xhr.send(formData);
                }
            }
        }
    
        // insert into page
        document.body.appendChild(input);

        // simulate a click -> opens browser file dialog
        input.click();
    }
}
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, VideoUpload);

Then later just call
VideoUpload.TriggerUploadViaFileBrowser();

Here is a little fiddle to test the JavaScript side - the Unity c# -> Javascript should be no big magic and basically work out of the box (except I included some bad typos here ^^)
Instead of clicking on the Upload button you would simply trigger the same method from within the Unity WebGL application.
https://jsfiddle.net/wpj410at/
Disclaimer: The fiddle uses https://fakeapi.platzi.com/en/rest/files/ per default -> don't upload your most sensitive files!! ;)
